# How to modify the FrameTicks and the figure frame?

Tags: plotting, ticks

Recently, I am confused about the FrameTicks and Frame when I use the Mathematica. Is there someone can spend some time to read this post and help me? Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
(*Fig Up*)
Fig1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   ImagePadding -> {{60, 15}, {0, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1.05, 1.05}}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Plain], 
   FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 14, Plain], 
      None}, {Directive[Black, 14, Plain], None}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, None}];

(*Fig Mid*)
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/gN4wGqxe"]
JetCM = With[{colorlist = RGBColor @@@ jetColors}, 
   Blend[colorlist, #] &];
Fig2 = ParametricPlot[{x, y*Sin[x]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> {{60, 15}, {40, 1}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.5, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, All}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Plain], 
    FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, False}, {True, True}}, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 14, Plain], 
       None}, {Directive[Black, 14, Plain], 
       Directive[Black, 14, Plain]}}, FrameLabel -> {None, None}, 
    ColorFunction -> (JetCM[(1 - #2) + (25 (1 - #2)^2 ((1 - #2) - 
              1/2) (#2)^2)/(1 + 100 ((1 - #2) - 1/2)^2)] &)] /. 
   Line[v_, opts___] :> Line[v[[2 ;; -82]], opts];


(*Fig Down*)
Fig3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -12, 12}, ImageSize -> 810, 
   ImagePadding -> {{60, 15}, {33, 40}}, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1.05, 1.05}}, PlotPoints -> 60, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Plain], 
   FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1}, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, 14, Plain], 
      None}, {Directive[Black, 14, Plain], None}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {None, None}];

(*Export*)
Fig = Grid[{{Fig1, Fig1}, {Fig2, Fig2}, {Fig3, SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Alignment -> Bottom]
Export["Fig.jpg", Fig, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

Then I got this figure:
[image]

The frame ticks are not shown.
I read some posts which suggest to export the figure as PDF format.
Then I tried this code:

```
Export["Fig.pdf", Fig, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

I got this result:
[image]

Here, the frame ticks can be shown normally, but why the figure frames have different resolutions?
I mean the frame "left", "right", "up" and "down" lines are drawn in different thicknesses and colors (black or grey).

Other problems are:

1. The x ticks are too short, how to draw them a little longer? I found several posts about this question, and I tried them. However, I still have not solved this problem.
2. About the y-axis, I want to draw the y ticks outside.
3. How to delete the texts "0.5" and "-0.5" of the y-axis, but still remain ticks drawing?

Can someone provide methods to solve the problems? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get the first picture grid, just the second. V12.0.0.

Comment: Hi, Steffen. Thank you for your reply. I use Mathematica 12. My main problem is that I do not know how to draw the frame ticks outside and how to delete the text of frame ticks. Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: Look up the corresponding documentation pages or browse this community with atomic search phrases for a solution.